# Adjusting summary totals when inputing data

Tags: data-entry, cognitive-load

Our application currently shows the budget of a group of line items at the bottom of the page. When you make an edit to a line item, the budget changes. When you make the change the old budget remains and a new on pops up in red. I find that these two numbers posed next to each other is a strain on the user's cognitive ability.

What are some better examples and/or solutions to this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Thinking some sort of meter that's usually seen in budget-related software might be more readable.

Comment: What if the new budget is substantionally bigger than the old one?